# Linq join static guid

Tags: linq, left-join

```
select ca.Name,l.ListName,ci.EntityId,ci.EntityType,c.FullName from List l

inner join Contact c on c.ContactId = 'D48457AB-C0B5-E211-838F-000C29DFF60A'
inner join CampaignItem ci on ci.EntityId = l.ListId 
inner join Campaign ca on ca.CampaignId = ci.CampaignId
where l.CreatedFromCode = 2
and ci.EntityType = 4300
```

How can I join static guid in Linq?

Here is my linq statement . I get excepetion when I run this query. How Can I join static Guid into my query?

```
var list = (from li in context.ListSet
                        join lm in context.ListMemberSet on li.ListId.Value equals lm.ListId.Id
                        join c in context.ContactSet on lm.EntityId.Id equals on new Guid("D48457AB-C0B5-E211-838F-000C29DFF60A")
                        join ci in context.CampaignItemSet on li.ListId.Value equals ci.EntityId
                        join cam in context.CampaignSet on ci.CampaignId.Id equals cam.CampaignId.Value
                        select new
                        {
                            ListId = li.ListId,
                            ListType = li.Type,
                            MemberType = li.CreatedFromCode,
                            EntityType = lm.EntityType,
                            EntityId = lm.EntityId,
                            ContactNumber = c.trd_CustomerNumber,
                            CampaignRelatedEntity = ci.EntityType,
                            CampaignName = cam.Name == null ? string.Empty : cam.Name,
                            CampaignCode = cam.CodeName == null ? string.Empty : cam.CodeName,
                            Objective = cam.Objective == null ? string.Empty : cam.Objective,
                            CampaignType = cam.TypeCode == null ? string.Empty : ((FinansCrm.BusinessLibrary.Utils.XrmHelper.OptionSetInfo)XrmHelper.GetOption(service, Campaign.EntityLogicalName, "typecode", cam.TypeCode.Value)).Label,
                            BeginDate = cam.ActualStart == null ? string.Empty : cam.ActualStart.Value.ToString(),
                            EndDate = cam.ActualEnd == null ? string.Empty : cam.ActualEnd.Value.ToString(),
                            CampaignId = cam.CampaignId.Value
                        }).ToList()
                           .Where(p => p.ListType.Value.Equals(false) && p.EntityType.Equals(Contact.EntityLogicalName) &&
                                  p.MemberType.Value.Equals(Contact.EntityTypeCode) && p.ContactNumber.Equals(id) &&
                                  p.CampaignRelatedEntity.Equals(List.EntityLogicalName))
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you show your (preliminary) linq statement first? It is hard to answer this from SQL code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear how you `ContactSet` is connected to the other sets in your query, but you can solve this by using `where` in stead of `join`:

```
var guid = new Guid("D48457AB-C0B5-E211-838F-000C29DFF60A");

var list = (
  from li in context.ListSet
  join lm in context.ListMemberSet on li.ListId.Value equals lm.ListId.Id
  join ci in context.CampaignItemSet on li.ListId.Value equals ci.EntityId
  join cam in context.CampaignSet on ci.CampaignId.Id equals cam.CampaignId.Value
  let c = context.ContactSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContactId == guid)
  select new
  { ...
```

Which is a disguised `where`: `FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContactId == guid)` is short for `Where(x => x.ContactId == guid).FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: Thanks Gert. Let keyword is my solution:)

Answer (score 0):

There are no Guid literals in the C# language so you'll have to use `Guid.Parse`, which works in my testing in LINQ to SQL

```
from l in List
join c in Contact on Guid.Parse("D48457AB-C0B5-E211-838F-000C29DFF60A") equals c.ContactId
join ci in CampaignItem ci on l.ListId equals ci.EntityId
join ca in Campaign on ci.CampaignId equals ca.CampaignId
where l.CreatedFromCode == 2 && ci.EntityType == 4300
select new {ca.Name,l.ListName,ci.EntityId,ci.EntityType,c.FullName}
```

This is a naive implementation, there could be optimizations for this query.

As an added optimization, you can store the Guid to a static readonly variable in your class but you'll have to pay this price at type initialization

```
private static readonly Guid contactId = Guid.Parse("D48457AB-C0B5-E211-838F-000C29DFF60A");
```